# How to test the access of protected route guard with in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-router, vue-test-utils

I implemented a route guard to protect the `/settings` route with the vue-router method `beforeEnter()`.

**I try to test that the route is protected to admins only**.

I am using Vuejs 2, Vue-router, Vuex and vue-test-utils.

**router.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    ..., // other routes
    {
      path: '/settings',
      name: 'Settings',
      component: () => import('./views/settings'),
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        next(store.state.isAdmin);
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

the **unit test**:

```
  test('navigates to /settings view if the user is admin', () => {
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(Vuex);
    localVue.use(VueRouter);
    const router = new VueRouter();

    const wrapper = shallowMount(App, {
      stubs: ['router-link', 'router-view'],
      localVue,
      mocks: {
        $store: store
      },
      router
    });
    wrapper.vm.$route.push({ path: '/settings' });
    // test if route is set correctly
  });
```

current logs output:

> wrapper.vm.$route` is undefined.

How can I mount the App correctly and access the router? How can I test the current route to verify that the admin user has been redirected succesfully?

Comment: https://github.com/mcibique/vue-testing-examples#testing-navigation-guards doesn't fully answer your question but points you to a direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank logan for the [link](https://github.com/mcibique/vue-testing-examples#testing-navigation-guards). It seems like the best possible solution:

As of now there is no easy way to test navigation guards. If you want to simulate the event triggering by calling `router.push` function, you are going to have a hard time. A better easier solution is to call the guard manually in `beforeEach()`, but even this solution doesn't have a clean approach. See the following example:

**beforeRouteEnter**

```
// my-view.js
class MyView extends Vue {
  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    next(function (vm) {
      vm.entered = true;
    });
  }
}
// my-view.spec.js
it('should trigger beforeRouteEnter event', function () {
  const view = mount(MyView);
  const spy = sinon.spy(view.vm.$options.beforeRouteEnter, '0'); // you can't just call view.vm.beforeRouteEnter(). The function exists only in $options object.

  const from = {}; // mock 'from' route
  const to = {}; // mock 'to' route
  view.vm.$options.beforeRouteEnter[0](to, from, cb => cb(view.vm));

  expect(view.vm.entered).to.be.true;
  expect(spy).to.have.been.called;
});
```

Comment: Worked for me too. Maybe one addition: if you want also to test if `ǹext` was called then you need to wrap it with a mock function: `const next = jest.fn(cb => cb(wrapper.vm));`. The assert: `expect(next).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Comment: @mrp don't you have an error TypeError: cb is not a function ?